# Array.prototype.map can not be used for Promise?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I have an array of values and I want to create an array of promises to make parallel call on that. But why map function not work?

```
let myArray = [1,2,3];
myArray.map((n) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(n);
    });
});
console.log(myArray); // [1,2,3]
```

But when I try to push Promises to array can work as expected.

```
let myArray = [1,2,3];
let pArray = []
for(let n of myArray){
    pArray.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(i);
    }));
}
console.log(pArray); // [Promise,Promise,Promise]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this, since `map` doesn't modify array:

```
let myArray = [1,2,3];
let promiseArray = myArray.map((n) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(n);
    });
});
console.log(promiseArray);
```

Comment: Thank you, just realized that. You should edit the result comment in your answer though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the result of `map`.

```js
let myArray = [1, 2, 3];
let pArray = myArray.map((n) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(n);
  });
});
console.log(pArray); // [Promise,Promise,Promise]
```